# Why is sonar-runner analysis stuck in infinite loop at "Updating semaphore"

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

With debug enabled I see infinite amounts of this from the command line:

```
15:10:18.796 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:10:22.592 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
15:10:28.797 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:10:32.595 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
15:10:38.798 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:10:42.597 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
15:10:48.799 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:10:52.598 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
15:10:58.799 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:11:02.600 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
15:11:08.800 INFO  - 1742/58318 files analyzed, current is C:\work\product\product-dao\src\company\product\dao\account\correspondence\MFLetterCommissionStatmntDAO.java
15:11:12.602 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-product:Trunk
```

The specific class mentioned is small (~100 lines) but does contain some 'interesting' code - could that be the issue?

It's machine translated Powerbuilder sql so looks a little odd:

```
wkcm_sql_queue sqlq = new wkcm_sql_queue();
ins = new SqlInsert();
ins.INSERT(
  sqlq.sqlq_statement(),
  sqlq.sqlq_execution_date(),
  sqlq.sqlq_system_code())
.SELECT(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(ADD(new Literal("EXEC CMLetter_LetterRequest "), TO_CHAR(letgPrcsCodeId)), new Literal(" ")), new Literal(",")), new Literal("NULL,")), TO_CHAR(dsetClientId)), new Literal(" ")), new Literal(",")), new Literal("NULL,")), TO_CHAR(clpnCbcsCodeId)), new Literal(" ")), new Literal(",")), new Literal("NULL,")), new Literal("NULL,")), new Literal("NULL,")), new Literal("NULL,")), new Literal("NULL,")), new Literal("\"")), TO_CHAR(startDateIn)), new Literal("\"")), new Literal(",")), new Literal("\"")), TO_CHAR(endDateIn)), new Literal("\"")), new Literal(",")), new Literal("NULL")), 
  GET_SYSTEM_DATE(), 
  new Literal("MSTF").AS("col1"));

Database.insert(ins);
```

The remaining code is relatively straight forward.

Would anyone be able to help please?
Thanks

Comment: If this is generated code, is it expected that it is analyzed?

Comment: Only a small part (that above) is generated, so yes I would expect it all to be analysed. It's still valid Java.

Comment: It does appear to be related to the heavily nested 'ADD' calls - 19 nested calls seems to work but 20+ doesn't.  Is there something that controlls the max level of nested calls analysed?

Comment: This appears related to this bug which was reported last year (and for C++) https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/issues/294 - any idea when a Java fix might be released?

Comment: From the debug log:                                                                           09:45:50.016 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=1195878ms

Comment: It's a long shot, but it could be related to http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Nested-parentheses-bug-in-sonar-runner-4-2-tt5034408.html (probably a performance issue in the Java parser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed is a known performance issue with the parser: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-793

In the meantime, if the performances are unacceptable, you can exclude this particular file from the analysis using the SonarQube exclusions mechanism (http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/AgAe).

Comment: Thanks - I see the issue was raised in Dec - any rough ideas when a fix may be available please? –  unfortunately we cannot exclude the files were the issue occurs as there are too many of them.

Comment: I can't give you any precise time estimate - I highly encourage you to not wait on a fix but instead to exclude the files, folders, or projects that are currently slow to parse so that you are not blocked by this issue.